# Beamer: remove the title highlight

Tags: beamer, formatting, titles

I use the PaloAlto theme and the title of the title slide appears highlighted.

Is it possible to remove the highlight and modify the title font?

Comment: What you mean by highlighted? Which title do you mean? Frametitle, Title on first slide? Maybe you could provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/232#232).

Comment: @bloodworks I edited, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\author{(Author)}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Standard output of PaloAlto:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to customize the color and the font theme:

To change the font: this command should typeset your title in huge slanted shape

```
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge,serie=\slshape}
```

To change the color: this command should draw your title in yellow on red background

```
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=yellow,bg=red}
```